# Xcode 6.4 iOS Charts API Error

Tags: ios, xcode, ios-charts

I'm have a problem with a unresolved identifier 'dataPoints'
it is in the for loop and I've tried all I can but as I am fairly new to swift I can't seem to find the solution.

```
    var months: [String]!
func setChart(dataPoints: [String], values: [Double]) {
    barChartView.noDataText = "You need to provide data for the chart."

}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    months = ["Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec"]
    let unitsSold = [20.0, 4.0, 6.0, 3.0, 12.0, 16.0, 4.0, 18.0, 2.0, 4.0, 5.0, 4.0]

    setChart(months, values: unitsSold)
    var dataEntries: [BarChartDataEntry] = []
    for i in 0..<dataPoints.count {
        let dataEntry = BarChartDataEntry(value: values[i], xIndex: i)
        dataEntries.append(dataEntry)
    }

    let chartDataSet = BarChartDataSet(yVals: dataEntries, label: "Units Sold")
    let chartData = BarChartData(xVals: months, dataSet: chartDataSet)
    barChartView.data = chartData
```

Comment: What is the error and which chart library are you using?

Comment: I'm using the iOS charts Api library https://github.com/danielgindi/ios-charts and the error I'm getting is an use of unresolved identifier 'dataPoints' its for the For loop code I've included

Comment: Where is `dataPoints` declared, I see you are using it but where is in either passed to you method or declared.

Comment: I decelared it in a above function          var months: [String]!
    func setChart(dataPoints: [String], values: [Double]) {
        barChartView.noDataText = "You need to provide data for the chart."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using `dataPoints` in your for loop, but there is no such variable in the scope of `viewDidLoad()`.

In your comment, you mention declaring a `dataPoints` in the function `setChart()`, but that is local to that function, it does not apply to other functions.

From your code, it looks like you should be using `months` for the for loop.

On that note, you probably intend to be using `unitsSold` instead of `values` when creating your `BarChartDataEntry` object in that for loop.

Comment: Thank you so much for the advice, I've been scratching my head at this for the past couple days.